# Marker's descriptions do not show up in Mapbox-js

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I have a dataset, created in mapbox from an original GEOJson file, and later associated to a tileset (aslo in MapBox Studio). It was parsed fine, and I could inspect it in Studio>Dataset, all properties were parsed.

This tileset is then used as a layer on a stylep; the points are displayed, but the point's descriptions are not displayed when using MapBox-gl-js.

What do I have to do to display those descriptions when clicking on a waypoint?

note: Adding them by hand when creating the map isn't my preferred solution. Can this be done transparently from the original dataset saved on mapbox servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tagged this post as `mapbox-gl-js`, but refer to `MapBox-js` - which library are you using?

Assuming you mean Mapbox GL JS (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js), I modified [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-click/) example of displaying data from a GeoJSON source to use a tileset from Studio instead - but it's the same underlying data. You can see it [here](https://bl.ocks.org/samfader/822f7058f6184dcd74c4c5eb5d1e62b1).

Comment: Hi thanks, I use mapbox-gl-js. The example requires to add the points of interests’s descriptions via code, which i’d Like to avoid. Do you know if it is possible to have those pulled transparently from the original datasets. I already have the POI displayed, only the descriptions are missing.

Comment: Oops sorry, I clicked on the un modified example, your modification seems to be what I want. Let me give it a try, and i’ll Get back to you!

Comment: Could you please detail where `` url: 'mapbox://samf.9bztwqzc'  and   "source-layer": "data-3b026x"`` are found?

Comment: That URL is a URL to a tileset I uploaded to my Mapbox account. You'd replace it with your tileset. The source-layer property is the layer within the tileset that I'm referencing. You can see source-layer names when viewing specific tilesets within your Mapbox account.

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/tileset/
https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/source-layer/

Comment: Not sure why, but I can't make this work, nothing shows up... Here's a jsfiddle with my code, copied from yours and with a data set. You should see a pin on 'Plaza del Toros', but there's nothing. I have no idea what's wrong with my data set/tileset... Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/awara/vxdu1y28/2/ Alternatively, I managed to make this work using styles, by querying the map features "var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {  layers: [layer_name]});"

Comment: @Alex the issue is that you are setting the icon to {icon}-15 - you need to use an icon in your spritesheet. For example, if you change that to bus-15, you'll see a marker. SVG images can be uploaded to your spritesheet in Mapbox Studio by clicking the Images link on the right-hand side.

Comment: ok, I understand now. Oh boy, all this time lost, I just can't believe this. Thanks for your patience man, really helpful. //Start RANT If anyone from mapbox is listening, you guys have the worst documentation and code instrumentation ever. Great maps, very neat, but the last 10% to make it work are just a f*cking nightmare. // End RANT.

Comment: @Alex I work at Mapbox :) Happy to pass feedback on, but can you provide some more specifics in terms of what tripped you up with our docs?

Comment: ooopss... :-\ Ok, in 600 char, that's going to be tough. First off, the doc is structured as internal dev docs (like api ref), that's not appropriate for ext. devs. who look entry points from a use case perspective. This makes the discovery process extremely tedious. Second, in all cases I've seen (mapbox 4 js), the api docs are incomplete 4 edge cases ex: mapbox.addLayer(layer,before) + "symbol" if the layer contains both points and closed polygons, the polygons are merged into points! Nowhere in the docs I could find how to handle this... Third, code instrumentation, ....

Comment: I understand that's extra work but there are so many fct params that either all fct calls ought to exit with an exception if params are missing or incomplete (some do, but not all), or you guys ought to make be a debug version of mapbox.js, to be used during development so we can sort out what's wrong, ex: see above, why is the code not complaining? Fourth (I may be inaccurate on this one), the whole thing dataset/tileset should be merged into one, and abstracted from us, OR please provide a way to merge 2 dataset into one tileset. Fifth: ah, when importing data into ...

Comment: an existing dataset, it would be nice to have the option to delete all previous data in one click, instead of selecting each points by hands. Anyway, that's icing on the cake. The most important for me is the doc structure, which is as friendly as the Unix man pages (ok, i push just a little, but not that much). The consequence is that all your code examples are disconnected from one another, so it's difficult to have a linear approach to solving use cases (and btw maintaining that doc must be a pain). If you want to see what great doc structures look like, check ...

Comment: this https://docs.parseplatform.org, where there's an api doc, and also a dev guide that addresses the much needed dev tasks when starting with the sdk, using a real life (albeit generic) dev scenario. For mapbox, you will probably end up splitting such guide between GIS dev, and conventional app dev, the former may need exotic stuff, while the latter, it's always pretty much the same. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - great feedback @Alex. I know I just asked you to write it here, but would you mind writing in to help@mapbox.com with this info so I can pass it directly to our docs team?